# Standard mathematical input to type-set output using python

Tags: python, math

I am looking at converting a standard mathematical user input such as

> int(3cos(x)+2)

To latex

> $\int cos(3x) dx$

And then converting that latex expression to a typsetted math image that can be used on a GUI in real time

How could this be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867028/converting-a-python-numeric-expression-to-latex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also generate the latex expression into an image with `sympy`.

Check the documentation of sympy.
Here's an example:

```
latexexpr = sin(sqrt(x**2 + 20)) + 1 
preview(latexexpr, viewer='file', filename='result.png')
```

Result:
[image: Result]

Comment: Great, just getting a runtime error RuntimeError: latex program is not installed

Comment: Thought i had texlive installed, turns out not on this vm, might have solved the problem

Comment: Its working fine, im facing one issue though, i am unable to change the font size and the background colour of the output , i have tried to use preamble from the documentation but to no avail.